# Linking an array to another class in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, linker

I am working on a game of tic-tac-toe for class and in one class I create a Board object which contains a String array and then pass it to a player class.  However I cannot figure out how to allow me to use this information in the new class.  Can anybody here give me some pointers?

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        //new tic-tac-toe board
        Board board = new Board();

        //two new players (computer and human)
        Player computer = new Player(board, "X");   //Give computer player access to board and     assign as X.
        Player human = new Player(board, "O");      //Give human player access to board and assign as O.
```

and the class I'm trying to use it in

```
 package outlab5;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Player {
     private String[][] currentBoard;
     private String move;
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


     public Player(Board inBoard, String inMove){
        move = inMove;
    }
    public void computerMove(){
        boolean valid = false;
    while(!valid){
        int moveCols = (int)(Math.random()*4);
        int moveRows = (int)(Math.random()*4);

        System.out.print(currentBoard[0][0]);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps your `String[]` should be some kind of class. Maybe `Board`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your Board class has a field representing the String[][] array, which you are looking for.
In your player class, store the borad object properly.

```
public class Player {
 private String[][] currentBoard;
 private String move;
 private Board board; //define a variable
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


 public Player(Board inBoard, String inMove){
    board = inBoard;
    move = inMove;
}
```

You dont show the code of Board class, so i have to guess how you may access the string[][],probably the Board class provides some get-Methods, to get access to the string array.

```
String[][] currentBoard = board.get....(); //this call must be placed in a method
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, of how you can do your application.

***Board Class***

```
public class Board {
    // TODO : Stuff and Stuff ( Where your 3x3 Matrix may be )
}
```

***Player Abstract Class***

```
abstract class Player {

    private final Board board;
    private final String move;

    public Player(Board _board, String _move) {
        this.board = _board;
        this.move = _move;
    }

    public void playerMove() {
        // TODO : Default Movement Actions
    }

    public void playerWin() {
        // TODO : Default Event on Player Win
    }
}
```

***Computer Class***

```
public class Computer extends Player {
    public Computer(Board _board, String _move) {
        super(_board, _move);
    }

    @Override
    public void playerMove() {
        // TODO : Computer Related Movements ( Like AI )
        super.playerMove();
    }

    @Override
    public void playerWin() {
        // TODO : Computer Related Events for Computer ( Like Increase Dif )
        super.playerWin();
    }
}
```

***Human Class***

```
public class Human extends Player {
    public Human(Board _board, String _move) {
        super(_board, _move);
    }

    @Override
    public void playerMove() {
        // TODO : Human Related Movements ( Like I/O )
        super.playerMove();
    }

    @Override
    public void playerWin() {
        // TODO : Human Related Events on Win ( Like Score )
        super.playerWin();
    }
}
```